# mirror modifier duplicated my body

Tags: modeling, weight-painting, mirror

I need to mirror the changes i am doing in the weights of my character from the left side to right side, but when i clic to add mirror modifier , it duplicates the whole body

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear why mirroring if without Mirror modifier you already have full mesh. Do you want to mirror only weights? Do you want to substitute existing half of mesh with the mirrorred part?

Comment: i want to mirror only weights i paint

Comment: Then either remove half of the body or use mirroring vertex groups (provided that bones are named accordingly), see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9390/how-can-i-mirror-weight-painting and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44882/how-to-mirror-copy-existing-vertex-weights

Answer (score 1):

With the Fast Carve Addon it is simple to use.

Download the addon [here](https://github.com/jayanam/fast-carve)

Just weight paint one side. In the object mode -> Tool shelf -> Fast carve -> symmetrize. Click on the axis need. (If you have painted on X axis click on the X axis. It will symmetrize on the negative X axis).

[image]